# Delta rpms and presto with yum

Tags: rpm

When you use delta rpm's with presto or without even, do they rely on you having the original rpm on hand, or do they download both the original and the difference between the original and then construct it? (specifically with yum)

Does presto or any other system need to be keeping a cache of all installed rpm's for delta rpms to work?

Do delta rpms work without presto, or are the integrated?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I encourage you to test these scenarios and report back.

Comment: No prob, just made a post of what I found

Answer (score 2):

I did some more research and here is what I found

**deltarpms** are used across multiple distributions and will work without presto. **Presto is a plugin for Yum which takes advantage of them.**

There are three main tools to work with deltas in fedora

**[deltarpm package]**

**applydeltarpm** -- this reconstructs a new rpm from a deltarpm and either an *installed* or *on hand* rpm file.

**combinedeltarpm** -- takes multiple deltas and combine them so they can be applied sequentially.

**makedeltarpm** -- create a delta rpm by contrasting two related rpms